What could be wrong in this PYTHON PYPEG2 grammar definition?
I need to define a grammar to parse the code below:
P1 ATTACKS p2  // P1 represents a pawn in chess game and p2 represents an opponent pawn
OR
P1 DEFENDS P2
OR
P1 IATTACKS p2,p3
OR
P1 IDEFENDS P2,P3
In order to do that I wrote the Python code below:
import pypeg2 as g

// actor() is a symbol representing a piece of chess game and a number associated to it
def actor(): return g.re.compile(r"[KQRNBPFS]\d", g.re.IGNORECASE)

// this class is a symbol which defines a kind of action in chess game between two or more pieces, IATTACKS means INDIRECT ATTACK and so on

class SceneryAction(str):
    grammar = g.Enum(g.K("ATTACKS"), g.K("DEFENDS"), g.K("IATTACKS"), g.K("IDEFENDS")) 

// this class represents an action occurring and must be parsed as an actor (piece) doing some action over another actor (piece)

class SceneryFrame(str):
    grammar = actor(), SceneryAction(), (actor(), g.csl(actor())), g.endl


The final goal of this grammar is to define a language for pattern representation in chess games.
However, when I try to parse this line:
k = g.parse("P1 ATTACKS p1\n",SceneryFrame)

I got this error:
  File "d:\Documents\Projects\Python\StratVision\PATLANParser.py", line 62, in <module>
    k = g.parse("P1 ATTACKS p1\n",SceneryFrame)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pypeg2\__init__.py", line 667, in parse
    t, r = parser.parse(text, thing)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pypeg2\__init__.py", line 794, in parse
    raise r
  File "<string>", line 1
    P1
       ^
SyntaxError: expecting match on [KQRNBPFS]\d


What have you tried so far?

I need a grammar to parse a string like this: P1 ATTACKS p2, where P1 and P2 are actor() and ATTACKS is an action type. Action type can be any of these symbols: "ATTACKS", "DEFENDS", "IATTACKS", "IDEFENDS". I think the problem may bem in the class SceneryAction, which specifies the action type expected. I hope I have answered your question.

Well your error is expecting a match of a text and thing, and attacks seem more like a SceneryAction rather than a SceneryFrame. Also comment your code, at least for SO questions, your variable names are very hard to decipher.

SceneryFrame grammar should expect an actor(), followed by a SceneryAction() and followed by a list of actor(). It would be the case that SceneryAction() should be a function instead of a class?
